# передать переменную из функции в другую функцию, созданную до этого

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("бот бомж версия")
        self.root.geometry("300x250")
    
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Напиши запрос кожаный ублюдок:")
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "бот:" + str(self.text_bot))
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

        self.txt = tk.Entry(self.root, width = 30)
        self.txt.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text = "отправить запрос", command = self.Parser)
        self.btn.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def Parser(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.set_window_position(1900,1004)
        self.request = self.txt.get()
        
        self.driver.get("https://trychatgpt.ru/#rec607352631")
        
        self.search_line = self.driver.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "input")
        self.search_button = self.driver.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "send")

        self.search_line.send_keys(self.request)
        self.search_button.click()
        
        sleep(20)
        self.ordinary_class = self.driver.find_elements(by = By.CLASS_NAME, value = "message")
        for i in range(0, len(self.ordinary_class)):
            if i == (len(self.ordinary_class)-1):
                self.bot_answer = self.ordinary_class[i]
                
        self.text_bot = self.bot_answer.text
        self.driver.quit()           
Bot()
```

Знаю, код может быть кривой и немного не логичный, но всё же. К сути, есть переменная self.text_bot её надо передать из Parser(self) в **init**(self) в self.Label. Если можно, то с минимальными изменениями в коде.

Answer (score 0):

есть небольшое пожелание, оставляй библиотеки, которые используешь.
давай разберемся как работают классы:
создадим небольшой класс, имя `test`, входные данные `a` и `b`.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def two(self):
        return self.a, self.b
```

понимаешь, если ты делаешь переменные через `self`, они доступны везде, даже если так: `print(test.a)`. в классе, `self` это сам класс. через него ты можешь получить доступ ко всем переменным класса, созданным через `self`. но если ты хочешь, чтобы они были не доступны за пределами класса, делай через `global`, пример:

```
global a, b
```

перейдем к решению проблемы:
можно сделать вот так:

```
class Bot():
    def __init__(self, lbl="Напиши запрос кожаный ублюдок: "):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("бот бомж версия")
        self.root.geometry("300x250")
    
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = lbl)
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "бот:" + str(self.text_bot))
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

        self.txt = tk.Entry(self.root, width = 30)
        self.txt.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text = "отправить запрос", command = self.Parser)
        self.btn.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def Parser(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.set_window_position(1900,1004)
        self.request = self.txt.get()
        
        self.driver.get("https://trychatgpt.ru/#rec607352631")
        
        self.search_line = self.driver.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "input")
        self.search_button = self.driver.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "send")

        self.search_line.send_keys(self.request)
        self.search_button.click()
        
        sleep(20)
        self.ordinary_class = self.driver.find_elements(by = By.CLASS_NAME, value = "message")
        for i in range(0, len(self.ordinary_class)):
            if i == (len(self.ordinary_class)-1):
                self.bot_answer = self.ordinary_class[i]
                
        self.text_bot = self.bot_answer.text
        self.driver.quit()
        self.__init__(lbl=self.text_bot)
Bot()
```

если не работает, пожалуйста, напиши библиотеки и дай знать.

Answer (score 0):

Всё что вы объявляете в методе `__init__` через `self` становится доступным и в других методах класса, поэтому вам не нужно ничего никуда передавать. Можно "на месте" всё обновить.

```py
class Bot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.label =  tk.Label(self.root, text='бот:')
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)
 
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, text='click me', command=self.parser)
        self.btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def parser(self):
        self.label.config(text='какой-то текст')
```

Так при вызове метода `parser` текст в элементе обновится.